# How can fusion within the sun be possible if there is no such thing as helium-2 (2 protons, no neutrons)

Tags: particle-physics, astrophysics, fusion

As stated in the question where does the sun(or other star) get the necessary neutron in order to produce the Helium atom? and how does this process occur (explain how the neutron incorporates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sun gets its energy from the pp-chain. The first step is the two protons forming the diproton (Helium-2):
$$
\,^1_1H+\,^1_1H\to\,^2_2He+\gamma
$$
where the $\gamma$ is the photon (of energy about half an MeV). This quickly [$\beta^+$-decays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission) into a deuterium by converting a proton into a neutron:
$$
\,^2_2He\to\,^2_1D+e^++\nu_e
$$
where $e^+$ is the positron and $\nu_e$ the electron neutrino.